# Volley send JsonArrayRequest via POST with JsonObject data

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I would like to create JsonArrayRequest using Volley POST but I need to put JSON parameters to the request which look like this

```
{"filter":{"minLat":15.0,"minLng":14.0,"maxLng":12.0,"maxLat":16.2,"validOnly":true,"groupDistance":1,"vehicleType":1,"serviceTypes":[1,2]},"username":"email@email.cz","securityToken":"securityToken"}
```

And I'm not able to figure it out. Is there somebody who can help me?
Thank you

Comment: Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html

Comment: Thank you, i can make custom request, but I don't know how to put object "filter" to Map<String,String>, is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

If not too late and your issue hasn't been solved. IMO, you can init your JSONOjbect like the following:

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jsonObject2;
        try {
            jsonObject.put("minLat", 15.0);
            jsonObject.put("minLng", 140);
            ...

            jsonObject2 = new JSONObject().put("filter", jsonObject);               
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Then, use `jsonObject2` in your request. Hope this helps!