# Post JSON Array to web server using jsonRquestObject in android

Tags: android, android-volley, android-json

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
        Const.URL_LOGIN, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

Does the above code send JSON Object to a particular URL?

Comment: seriously, not possible... or maybe: because json that **you had pass** to the request is null ?

Comment: @Selvin how do  i then send data to web server? any links or suggestions ?

Comment: sure ... here is an extremely useful link: https://google.com

Comment: :) that i know. could'nt find much thats the reason im here

Comment: Hi! For your question "How to send data...", you can take a look at some of my answers available in S.O such as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177697/volley-send-jsonarrayrequest-via-post-with-jsonobject-data/32217049#32217049) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197615/volley-send-jsonobject-to-server-with-post-method/32216762#32216762)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the JSONObject class from Volley, normally has two conditions:

the third param is the json you want to send.

If you use:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
    Const.URL_LOGIN, null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
}
. 
.
.
```

You you are using the first constructor, that means you want to send some object in your body request, and if you send null, volley in the constructor do this param.toString(), so if you send null, imagine, null.toString(), obviously will crash, that is not possible operation of a null object.

So the other option is to use the second constructor:

```
   JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
        Const.URL_LOGIN,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    }
    . 
    .
    .
```

You dont have to send the third param (the param/json body), so this constructor auatomatically has the condition that you dont want to send nothing to the server. I think you have to use the second constructor, otherwise could fail.

Regards.